# Wireless Packet captures - VMware

Tags: networking, wifi, wireshark

Software: Wireshark
Is it possible to analyse Wireless Packet captures on VMWare using Linux Ubuntu OS? I ask this as I’m using Windows for my computer but I’m struggling to get all the information I need so I’ve had to resort to a virtual machine.

On windows, wireless packet captures will appear as if they were on a wired network (the 802.11 header is replaced by an Ethernet II) It is possible to capture raw 802.11 traffic on Windows, but only a small number of network cards support it. I’ve been told It is much easier to capture 802.11 raw data using Linux or a MAC compute

Thanks

Comment: On Windows 7 or later, does npcap support monitor "rfmon" mode on your interface?  There will be a Monitor Mode checkbox in Wireshark's Capture > Options table,  and `%windir%\system32\npcap\WlanHelper.exe  {Interface Name or GUID} modes`  will contain monitor.

Comment: Not sure to be honest but I can find out, thanks. How come I can’t look at wireless captures on VMWare? I’m pretty knew to networking just getting an understanding of it all

Comment: I didn't say you couldn't capture on VMware. Just that npcap is your best chance for monitor mode for Wireshark on Windows. Although driver support is bad.

Comment: Ok thanks. What are the solutions of wireless capturing on VMware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a Linux LiveCD.

If you only want to capture for a while, just download a Linux live image, write it to a DVD or USB thumb drive and boot from it. There are images exactly for such cases which will already contain Wireshark, but any will do. You can install software on a LiveCD session (it will just be gone on the next reboot).

Boot the live session, run Wireshark, store the captured data somewhere. You can analyze the data later with Wireshark on Windows.